# Do Java 8 Streams support any form of range variable?

Tags: java, c#, linq, java-8

In C#, using Linq, I can define a range variable (length in this case) to be used within the expression, e.g:

```
var result = from name in names
             let length = name.Length //assume this is expensive so we don't want to compute it twice
             select new MyClass(length * length, length)
```

Is there a way of defining a similar range variable (i.e. such as length in the above example) in Java 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if that is what you are looking for, but how about something like this

```
List<MyClass> result = names.stream()
                            .map(name->name.length)
                            .map(length->new MyClass(length*length, length))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I like this the best so far, as it's the most concise elegant solution, and better than my example in the comments of @dkatzel answer, as it doesn't group the creation of the range variable with the projection to the MyClass

Comment: I guess .map(name -> name.length) could be replaced with .map(String::length) too, but it's debatable whether that syntax is actually more readable or not...

Comment: Yes, if `name` is String then you should be able to use `String::length` without problems.

Comment: @Richard - this is the obvious solution. I was about to suggest it, too, but I was presuming that your example was simplified. And it does not answer your original question of how to support "range variables" in Java 8 streams.

Answer (score 1):

A- Java does not know sql-syntax so no let keyword.

B- The let keyword turns into a select of an anonymous type. Java also does not know anonymous types.

I think the following is somewhat similar to what LINQ creates behind the scenes:

```
private class TransparentIdentifier
{
    String value;
    int length;

    public TransparentIdentifier(String s) {
        this.value = value;
        length = value.length();
    }

    public int getLength() { return length; }
    public String getValue() { return value; }

}

names.stream()
   .map(name -> new TransparentIdentifier(name))
   .map(ti => new MyClass(ti.getLength() * ti.getLength(), ti.getLength()));
```

Comment: or shouldn't `names.stream().map(name -> { int length = name.getLength(); return new MyClass(length * length, length); }` work, too?

Comment: @chiccodoro When using LINQ in .NET I always feel like I've failed (in terms of readability) when using multi-line lambdas, but I guess this is going to be quite a common usage pattern in Java 8, due to the lack of extra sugar / anonymous types (and to avoid creating extra classes to mimic .net like anonymous types.

Comment: @Dennis_E it seems there is a trade off between creating a new class or accepting more verbose lambdas in this case, due to the lack of anonymous types as you mentioned.

Comment: I think the 'verbose lambda' is a pretty neat solution, but I always prefer C# over Java. C# is still miles ahead.

Comment: You can of course also do the same thing in C#: names.Select(name => { int len = name.Length; return new MyClass(len * len, len); }) but it's not the same as using 'let'

Comment: @Dennis_E by verbose, I mean it's just heavier on syntax than a nice declarative Linq expression (that let allows you to form, but obviously isn't available in Java). I find in C# if I need multi-line lamdas then there is generally a better way to work it to give a more elegant solution - but that may not always be the case in Java 8.

Comment: @Richard, Dennis, like Denis already noted in the answer, the `let` keyword only exists for the "sql-like" syntax in C#. If you use LINQ method chains, you have two options: Either map to a anonymous object (see B in the answer), or use a lambda method instead of a lambda expression, and define the variable in that method. The same holds for Java. The only difference is that Java has no anonymous objects. (Though nothing stops you from using a dictionary or other generic data structure - you only lose type safety, in contrast to anonymous objects in C#)

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
names.forEach(name ->{
        int length = name.length();
        list.add(new MyClass(length*length, length));
    });
```

You can probably turn this into a custom `Collector` as well.

**EDIT**
changed Collection of MyClasses from Set to List since to support be duplicate lengths

Comment: Similar comment to previous answer, I possibly need to accept verbose multi-line lambdas in Java 8 more often than in C#. To improve readability I guess the expression could be extracted as a field so that we end up with names.stream().map(toMyClass).collect(toList()) (where toMyClass is the extracted lambda).

Comment: @Richard Marriott: I don’t see where a multi-line lambda is more verbose than a multi-line LINQ expression. If LINQ were as dense as, e.g. regular expression syntax, I could see the point of integrating another special-purpose syntax within an existing programming language. But as it is, I’m glad that Java doesn’t have a redundant alternative syntax for saying the same thing just differently without any benefit.